# How to Disable 2 Components with the same Name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i need to disable 2 components which are scripts.
They both have the same name (RotateAround)
I wrote some code which will disable rotatearound 30 seconds after the Game starts running.
Here is the Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CompDel : MonoBehaviour
{
        public Text TimeText;

    public float Timer = 30;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            Timer = Timer - 1 * Time.deltaTime;


            if (Timer < 0)
            {
                this.GetComponent<RotateAround>().enabled=false;
            };

            if (Timer > -10)
            {
                TimeText.enabled = false;
            };

            if (Timer < 0)
            {
                TimeText.enabled = true;
            };

            if (Timer < -10)
            {
                int buildIndex = 1;
                //Load the scene with a build index
                SceneManager.LoadScene(buildIndex);
            }
        } 
}
```

So how to edit this so i can disble both instances of the RotateAround Script

Comment: try `GetComponents` it will return a component array. https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponents.html

Comment: can you tell how to use them

Comment: i am new to proggraming

Comment: @nithi554

var components = this.GetComponents<RotateAround>();
foreach(var component in components)
{
component.enabled = false;
}

Comment: idk where i should add it so add it into my code if possible(Post an answer)

Comment: hello it does not work

Comment: i am creating a model of the solar system

Comment: i want earth to stop rotating around the sun and revolving around itself

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how you can do it find all object of type RotateAround put them in array and use foreach loop to disale it.

```
public Text TimeText;

public float Timer = 30;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Timer = Timer - 1 * Time.deltaTime;
    
    if (Timer < 0)
    {
        GetComponent();
        TimeText.enabled = true;
    }

    if (Timer > -10)
    {
        TimeText.enabled = false;
    }

    if (Timer < -10)
    {
        int buildIndex = 1;
        //Load the scene with a build index
        SceneManager.LoadScene(buildIndex);
    }
}

void GetComponent()
{
    var array = FindObjectsOfType<RotateAround>();
    foreach (var comp in array)
    {
        comp.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: just a minor pet peeve, the method name isnt descriptive at all - id say its even misleading.

Comment: @yes .. your name says it already ^^ it is also hiding the built-in `Component.GetComponent` which is really bad!

Comment: @yes I'm just giving an idea. you can choose whatever name of function